# Laravel, first() vs loop

Tags: laravel

I have an object on which I can run first() but I don't know how to loop through it.

```
$types = $biz->types()->first();
echo $types->name; //works great and gives me the name
```

This works fine but if I try:

```
    $types = $biz->types(); //returns a BelongsToMany object
    foreach($types as $type){
        echo $type->name; //doesn't enter the loop at all
    }
```

Edit: the following wouldn't work:

```
 $biz->types; //returns an empty collection
```

This one doesn't give me anything and loop wouldn't initiate.

**My question: How do I loop through $types and not just the first one?**

PS: I wanted to focus on the loop and first so I didn't bring all the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should access it as a property, which gives you access to the Collection of models. Accessing it as a method gives you `QueryBuilder` as a result.

```
foreach($biz->types as $type) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: No, At least $biz->types() return a BelongsToMany object but $biz->types returns an empty collection.

Comment: Make sure your database is populated corretly. Can you add your model relationships to your post ?

Comment: It means there are no relations. I assume `$biz` is an Eloquent model and types is a relation. Unless there is something wrong with the relation it should work. You can try `$biz->types()->get()` if it gives you different result.

Comment: If `$model->relation()->first()` return data you should get the data with `$model->relation()->get()` or `$model->relation`. Just paste `types()` method here.

Comment: Thanks  Chris Cynarski. As you mentioned it I got curious that something might be wrong which was. I had customized the name of relationship fields wrongly.